# What is this blue smoke behind a wall?

Tags: enter-the-gungeon

I've found this wall often in the room with Muncher weapon crate, and now in the boss room:
[image]

[image]

I can't destroy it with my weapons or blanks. What is this wall? Is it just a distraction? Or is there a way to break through it?

Comment: For me it looks like water running down the wall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing special about this type of wall - it's just for decoration.  As noted in a comment, it appears to be water running down the cracks between the bricks.